# Send variable from component to sibling in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have the following template in my app.component.html

```
<div class="app-container">
  <app-header></app-header>
  <div class="content--wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

For simplicity, let's assume `header.component.html` looks like

```
<ul>
  <li>el1</li>
  <li id="removable"><img src="some_icon.png"></li>
</ul>
```

And of course, I have pages loaded depending on the route selected.

What I want to achieve is to show #removable depending on which route I am currently on.

For example, `/another-component` route will load `AnotherComponent`.

The way I started is by setting a `@input() showElement` variable in the `HeaderComponent` and using it in the template like:

```
  <li id="removable" *ngIf="showElement"><img src="some_icon.png"></li>
```

and of course in `app.component.html` I would have something like

```
  <app-header [showElement]="booleanValue"></app-header>
```

Now the issue is that I dont know how to pass that `booleanValue` from the `AnotherComponent` added by the router-outlet.

I tried adding an `@Output()` in `AnotherComponent` that emits the `booleanValue` I want, in the constructor, but how can `AppComponent` use this value?

Am I in the right direction? Or is there another way that I am not aware of?

Comment: Create a service, inject it in both components. One component sets true/false to variable in that service, other component takes value of that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @incognito mentioned above you can create a service which is registered in the parent component and controls this.

Take a look at this plnkr for eg: https://plnkr.co/edit/mCgImmvlBDPCHoN61pEZ?p=preview

The title in the above example is hidden when you visit the Crisis Component.

1.

```
//app.component.ts
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class HideService {
  hide: boolean = false;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
  template: `
    <h1 *ngIf="!isHidden">Hide Title on Crisis Route</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="/crisis-center" routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Center</a></li>
    </ul>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
  providers: [HideService]
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private hideService: HideService) {}

  get isHidden() {
    return this.hideService.hide;
  }

}
```

2.

```
//Crisis Component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HideService} from './app.component';

@Component({
  template: `
    Crisis Component
  `
})
export class CrisisListComponent {
  constructor(private hideService: HideService) {
    this.hideService.hide = true;
  }
}
```

3.

```
//hero component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HideService} from './app.component';

@Component({
  template: `
    Hero Component
  `
})
export class HeroListComponent {

  constructor(private hideService: HideService) {
     this.hideService.hide = false;
  }

}
```

You could also use Routing Data to do this. More info here: https://angular.io/guide/router

```
{
  path: 'crisis-center',
  loadChildren: 'app/crisis-center/crisis-center.module#CrisisCenterModule',
  data: { preload: true }
},
```

Comment: Thank you! I like the solution with routes!