# Change header styles according to component in angular 4

Tags: html, angular

I have added a header in app.component.html and i need one section of the header to be altered according to the components being visited.

I don't know how to implement it.

I am using routing in the app so I cannot implement a parent-child relationship.

Comment: You can do this with https://angular.io/api/common/Location

Comment: You mean change based on the previous route?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366424/send-variable-from-component-to-sibling-in-angular-4

Answer (score 0):

Thank you takeradi,

I found my answer in the following link.

[Send variable from component to sibling in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366424/send-variable-from-component-to-sibling-in-angular-4)

It was a very simple solution but I was overthinking it.

Thank you.